# How to iterate a tree using BFS using a for loop?

Tags: breadth-first-search, pseudocode

I am iterating a tree using Breadth first search and I want to check whenever the iteration goes to a lower level in the tree each time to display a message and that using a pseudo code. I don't want to use the classic while-for loops but instead I want one for loop that is commented with (traverse BFS) like I do below it:

```
  PreviousNodeLevel ← null
  for node in tree do //(traverse BFS)
    if node ∈ children(PreviousNodeLevel) then // if the current node is a child of any element of PreviousNodeLevel
        display message // next level of nodes reached 
    else if PreviousNodeLevel != null then 
        PreviousNodeLevel ← null // next the next level case
    end if
    PreviousNodeLevel.insert(node)
  end for
```

Any idea if this pseudo-code is correct to adopt ?

Comment: why do you need the for loop -  is it to parallelize  or do you want to count the level ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there a problem? It is just a pity that you have to store **again** the nodes that are in a level, while the hidden BFS algorithm is already doing that.